# Tikzcd commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have been trying to draw the following diagram (see attached photo) but just can’t seem to get the syntax right. I have been looking at a  tikzcd tutorial off the net but clearly I haven’t quite figured it out. Any suggestions gratefully received.

[image: My diagram]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzcd}
   & C\\
   A\ar[r]\ar[d]\ar[ur] & B\ar[u]\\
   D\ar[ur]\ar[uur, bend left=75]
   \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like magic. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @User2020 You're welcome!